# Working with HTML files in iOS Dev (Swift + Xcode)

Tags: ios, sendgrid

I have an HTML file (a template file for sending email). I'm using [SendGrid](https://github.com/scottkawai/sendgrid-swift) to email users the receipt once they purchase something. I need to add some information to the HTML template file (pass a string values such as address, price, date of purchase, etc) before passing it to the SendGrid object.

A solution that came to my mind was to simply pass the HTML string but this is a bad solution since a template HTML will contain some javascript and other things.

What's the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure the best solution for this is to notify a service -> have the service send the HTML Script/Email or whatever it is you've made.

Sending the parameters you need to your backend/api and have that send the email.

Comment: is there a workaround for this unnecessary step? The sendgrid directly emails to the email address..

Comment: Unless you find a library like SendGrid that allows you to fully customize the  email it is you're sending, then no.

And from a business / scalability POV you should be handling everything in a backend/API rather then handle everything from inside the app itself, this library can someday not get supported anymore and you're left with a complaint because a customer didn't get a receipt fue to deprecated methods or whatnot.